# Error On Dependant Picklist field values in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I wanted a Quick Action button that also allowed for uploading a file. I have some fields that are picklist, and some fields that are dependent picklists. It worked fine until added the code I found for the dependent picklist fields and tried to add value="..." to

```
<ui:inputSelect aura:id="ERIDT1__Interview_Stage__c" value="{!v.Interview.ERIDT1__Interview_Stage__c}" change="{!c.onControllerFieldChange}"/>
```

and

```
<ui:inputSelect aura:id="ERIDT1__Interview_Decision__c" value="{!v.Interview.ERIDT1__Interview_Decision__c}" disabled="{!v.isDependentDisable}"/>
```

. When I add the value I get this error:
[image: Error]

If I don't add value there is no error, but it doesn't save the field. Thanks in advance for any help.

Apex Class:

```
public class Client_Int_Btn_Ctrl{

/*Method to save record of Forms, Documents & Evaluations with its related attachments
    @Param - interview   ==> record of Interview
    @Param - CTId       ==> Client Tracker Id
*/
@AuraEnabled
public static string saveRecord(ERIDT1__Forms_Documents_Evaluations__c interview, Id CTId)
{
    try
    {
        system.debug('Interview ? ' + interview);
        interview.ERIDT1__Client_Tracker__c = CTId;
        interview.recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.ERIDT1__Forms_Documents_Evaluations__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Interview Form').getRecordTypeId();
        upsert interview;
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw new AuraHandledException('This is the error: ' + e.getMessage());
    }

    return null;
}
@AuraEnabled  
public static Map<String,List<String>> getDependentOptionsImpl(string objApiName , string contrfieldApiName , string depfieldApiName){
    system.debug(objApiName + '##' + contrfieldApiName + '###' + depfieldApiName);

    String objectName = objApiName.toLowerCase();
    String controllingField = contrfieldApiName.toLowerCase();
    String dependentField = depfieldApiName.toLowerCase();

    Map<String,List<String>> objResults = new Map<String,List<String>>();
        //get the string to sobject global map
    Map<String,Schema.SObjectType> objGlobalMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();

    if (!Schema.getGlobalDescribe().containsKey(objectName)){
        System.debug('OBJNAME NOT FOUND --.> ' + objectName);
        return null;
     }

    Schema.SObjectType objType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName);
    if (objType==null){
        return objResults;
    }
    Bitset bitSetObj = new Bitset();
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> objFieldMap = objType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    //Check if picklist values exist
    if (!objFieldMap.containsKey(controllingField) || !objFieldMap.containsKey(dependentField)){
        System.debug('FIELD NOT FOUND --.> ' + controllingField + ' OR ' + dependentField);
        return objResults;     
    }

    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> contrEntries = objFieldMap.get(controllingField).getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> depEntries = objFieldMap.get(dependentField).getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
     objFieldMap = null;
    List<Integer> controllingIndexes = new List<Integer>();
    for(Integer contrIndex=0; contrIndex<contrEntries.size(); contrIndex++){            
        Schema.PicklistEntry ctrlentry = contrEntries[contrIndex];
        String label = ctrlentry.getLabel();
        objResults.put(label,new List<String>());
        controllingIndexes.add(contrIndex);
    }
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> objEntries = new List<Schema.PicklistEntry>();
    List<PicklistEntryWrapper> objJsonEntries = new List<PicklistEntryWrapper>();
    for(Integer dependentIndex=0; dependentIndex<depEntries.size(); dependentIndex++){            
           Schema.PicklistEntry depentry = depEntries[dependentIndex];
           objEntries.add(depentry);
    } 
    objJsonEntries = (List<PicklistEntryWrapper>)JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(objEntries), List<PicklistEntryWrapper>.class);
    List<Integer> indexes;
    for (PicklistEntryWrapper objJson : objJsonEntries){
        if (objJson.validFor==null || objJson.validFor==''){
            continue;
        }
        indexes = bitSetObj.testBits(objJson.validFor,controllingIndexes);
        for (Integer idx : indexes){                
            String contrLabel = contrEntries[idx].getLabel();
            objResults.get(contrLabel).add(objJson.label);
        }
    }
    objEntries = null;
    objJsonEntries = null;
    system.debug('objResults--->' + objResults);
    return objResults;
}
}
```

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="Client_Int_Btn_Ctrl" implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:appHostable,lightning:actionOverride,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
<aura:html tag="style">
    .cuf-content {
    padding: 0 0rem !important;
    }
    .slds-p-around--medium {
    padding: 0rem !important;
    }       
    .slds-modal__content{
    overflow-y:hidden !important;
    height:unset !important;
    max-height:unset !important;
    }
</aura:html>
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
<aura:attribute name="Interview" type="ERIDT1__Forms_Documents_Evaluations__c" default="{ 'sobjectType' : 'ERIDT1__Forms_Documents_Evaluations__c' }"/>
<aura:attribute name="Error" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="ObjectName" type="String" default="ERIDT1__Forms_Documents_Evaluations__c"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:attribute name="depnedentFieldMap" type="map" description="store controller(key)--> dependent(values) picklist value as a map." />
<aura:attribute name="isDependentDisable" type="boolean" default="true" description="use for, make disbale depandent field." />

<form class="slds-form--stacked mainForm">
    <aura:if isTrue="{! v.Error != null}">
            <div class="forcePageError">
                <div class="genericNotification">
                    <span class="genericError uiOutputText">
                        Review the errors on this page.
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p style="color:red">{!v.Error}</p>
    </aura:if>
    <br/>
    <div class="inputText">
        <div class="slds">
            <div class="slds slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid--pull-padded">
                <div class="slds-col--padded slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-2 slds-large-size--6-of-12">
                    <!--Controller Field-->
                    <div class="slds-form-element">
                        <label class="slds-form-element__label myLabel">Interview Stage</label>
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                            <ui:inputSelect aura:id="ERIDT1__Interview_Stage__c" value="{!v.Interview.ERIDT1__Interview_Stage__c}" change="{!c.onControllerFieldChange}"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-2 slds-large-size--6-of-12">
                    <!--Dependent Field-->
                    <div class="slds-form-element">
                        <label class="slds-form-element__label myLabel">Interview Decision</label>
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                            <ui:inputSelect aura:id="ERIDT1__Interview_Decision__c" disabled="{!v.isDependentDisable}"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form><br/><br/>
<div class="modal-footer slds-modal__footer"  style="height:60px">
    <lightning:button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="{!c.closeModel}" >Cancel</lightning:button> 
    <lightning:button class="slds-button slds-button--brand"  onclick="{!c.saveRecordWrapper}">Save</lightning:button>
</div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
doInit:function(component,event,helper){
    helper.fetchPicklistValues(component, 'eridt1__interview_stage__c', 'eridt1__interview_decision__c');
},

saveRecordWrapper:function(component,event,helper)
{
    var btn = event.getSource();
    btn.set("v.disabled", true);

    var Interview= component.get("v.Interview");
    helper.upload(component,Interview,btn);
},

closeModel: function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.Error", null);
    component.set("v.Interview", null);
    $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();


 },

   onControllerFieldChange: function(component, event, helper) {

      var controllerValueKey = event.getSource().get("v.value");

  var Map = component.get("v.depnedentFieldMap");

  if (controllerValueKey != '--- None ---') {

     var ListOfDependentFields = Map[controllerValueKey];
     helper.fetchDepValues(component, ListOfDependentFields);

  } else {
     var defaultVal = [{
        class: "optionClass",
        label: '--- None ---',
        value: '--- None ---'
     }];
     component.find('conState').set("v.options", defaultVal);
     component.set("v.isDependentDisable", true); 
  }
   }
})
```

And Helper:

```
({

upload: function(component, Interview, btn) {

    var action = component.get("c.saveRecord");
    action.setParams({
        interview: Interview,
        CTId:component.get("v.recordId")
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();

        if(state === "SUCCESS")
        {
            component.set("v.Error", null);
            component.set("v.Interview", null);
            btn.set("v.disabled", false);
            $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();  
            $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();

            var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            toastEvent.setParams({
                type: 'success',
                message: 'New Interview created. To edit entire record, look in the related lists.'
            });
            toastEvent.fire();
        }
        if(state === "ERROR")
        {
            var errors = response.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if(errors[0] && errors[0].message )
                {
                    component.set("v.Error", errors[0].message);
                }
            }
            btn.set("v.disabled", false);
        }

    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
fetchPicklistValues: function(component, controllerField, dependentField) {
  var action = component.get("c.getDependentOptionsImpl");

  action.setParams({
     'objApiName': component.get("v.ObjectName"),
     'contrfieldApiName': controllerField,
     'depfieldApiName': dependentField
  });
  action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
     if (response.getState() == "SUCCESS") {
        var StoreResponse = response.getReturnValue();

        component.set("v.depnedentFieldMap", StoreResponse);


        var listOfkeys = []; // for store all map keys (controller picklist values)
        var ControllerField = []; // for store controller picklist value to set on ui field. 

        for (var singlekey in StoreResponse) {
           listOfkeys.push(singlekey);
        }

        if (listOfkeys != undefined && listOfkeys.length > 0) {
           ControllerField.push({
              class: "optionClass",
              label: "--- None ---",
              value: "--- None ---"
           });
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < listOfkeys.length; i++) {
           ControllerField.push({
              class: "optionClass",
              label: listOfkeys[i],
              value: listOfkeys[i]
           });
        }
        component.find('ERIDT1__Interview_Stage__c').set("v.options", ControllerField);
     }
  });
  $A.enqueueAction(action);


},

   fetchDepValues: function(component, ListOfDependentFields) {
      var dependentFields = [];

  if (ListOfDependentFields != undefined && ListOfDependentFields.length > 0) {
     dependentFields.push({
        class: "optionClass",
        label: "--- None ---",
        value: "--- None ---"
     });

  }
  for (var i = 0; i < ListOfDependentFields.length; i++) {
     dependentFields.push({
        class: "optionClass",
        label: ListOfDependentFields[i],
        value: ListOfDependentFields[i]
     });
  }
  component.find('ERIDT1__Interview_Decision__c').set("v.options", dependentFields);
  component.set("v.isDependentDisable", false);
   }

})
```

Comment: That’s alot of code, aren’t you able to create a minimal reproduceable code sample? It will be easier to help you out. Thanks

Comment: Additionally, is there anything stopping you from using a lightning record edit form?

Comment: Lack of knowledge is the only thing stopping me! I will research the lightning record edit form and see if I can minimize the code.

Comment: it will also save you alot of server requests and will manage FLS and cRUD operations so it is worth looking into. Cheers

Comment: Thanks again glls! I read and worked a ton yesterday and I got it all working and with SO much less code using lighting:recordEditForm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding this for future users trying to implement custom components for interacting with records or creating new ones.

When possible, try leveraging the

- [lightning:recordEditForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_recordEditForm.htm)

> Represents a record edit layout that displays one or more fields, provided by lightning:outputField. This component requires API version 41.0 and later.
>   A lightning:recordEditForm component is a wrapper component that accepts a record ID and is used to display one or more fields and labels associated with that record using lightning:inputField. lightning:recordEditForm requires a record ID to display the fields on the record. It doesn't require additional Apex controllers or Lightning Data Service to display record data. This component also takes care of field-level security and sharing for you, so users see only the data they have access to.

Basic Usage Sample:

```
<aura:component>
<lightning:recordEditForm recordId="003XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" objectApiName="Contact">
    <lightning:messages />
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="FirstName" />
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="LastName" />
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Email" />
    <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" name="update" label="Update" />
</lightning:recordEditForm>
</aura:component>
```

downside(s) I have experienced:

- May take up to a second or two to load

Upsides:

- Easy setup (minimal code)
- Less code to maintain
- Handles Errors and displays to users
- Handles CRUD (No Apex)
- Handles FLS
- Supports Dependant Picklists